# Phone Book (Java) Task: Print all matches if only last name is entered

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, arraylist

I'm creating a phone book for an assignment and I'm stuck on this part. I need to print every match if the user didn't enter the first name. Currently, my program only print the first match.

Part of the instruction: If the user enters just the last name, the program goes through the entire array, printing out every match. If the user enters both first and last names, the program will print out the first match, then stop.

This is my search method in my PhoneBook class:

```
// use linear search to find the targetName.
// Return a reference to the matching PhoneEntry
// or null if none is found
public PhoneEntry search(String fName, String lName) {

    for (int j = 0; j < phoneBook.length; j++) {
        if (phoneBook[j].lastName.equals(lName)) {
            if (phoneBook[j].firstName.equals(fName) || fName.equals("")) {
                return phoneBook[j];
            }
        }
    }

    return null;

}
```

And this is my loop for prompting the user and printing the information in my Tester

```
do {

    // Prompt the user to enter the name
    System.out.print("Pleast enter the last name to search: ");
    lastName = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Please enter the first name to search: ");
    firstName = input.nextLine();

    // search for the person
    entry = pb.search(firstName.toUpperCase(), lastName.toUpperCase());

    // if found, print out the entry
    if (entry != null) {
        System.out.println(entry.firstName + " " + entry.lastName + ": " + entry.phone);
    }

    // if user enter quit, then say good bye
    else if ("quit".equals(lastName)) {
        System.out.println("Good Bye!");
    }

    // if not found, tell the user
    else {
        System.out.println("Name not found.");
    }

} while (!"quit".equals(lastName));
```

I just need to get the program to print all of the matches if only last name is entered. I'm new to arrays and I only know Java.

Thank you in advance! :)

**Update**

Thanks to @TyeolRik, I was able to do "something" about it. His way was using the cases way and sorry but I do not know how to do cases. I implemented his way into mine, but I do not know how to connect them between classes. I tried to put "return resultList" on the search method, but it didn't allowed me to because it is a PhoneEntry[] instead of PhoneEntry, and that is true, but I can't search it using "entry = pb.search(firstName.toUpperCase(), lastName.toUpperCase());" if it is an array type. I need help! Thank you guys.

This is my complete current code (I have 3 classes):

PhoneBook (ignore the add method because that is for something else that I'm doing for another instruction):

```
public class PhoneBook {

PhoneEntry[] phoneBook;
PhoneEntry[] resultList = new PhoneEntry[10];

// constructor
public PhoneBook() {

    phoneBook = new PhoneEntry[10];

    // load the phone book with data
    phoneBook[0] = new PhoneEntry("James", "Barclay", "(418) 665-1223");
    phoneBook[1] = new PhoneEntry("Grace", "Dunbar", "(860) 399-3044");
    phoneBook[2] = new PhoneEntry("Paul", "Kratides", "(815) 439-9271");
    phoneBook[3] = new PhoneEntry("Violet", "Smith", "(312) 223-1937");
    phoneBook[4] = new PhoneEntry("John", "Wood", "(913) 883-2874");
    phoneBook[5] = new PhoneEntry("John", "Smith", "(407) 123-4555");
}



// use linear search to find the targetName.
// Return a reference to the matching PhoneEntry
// or null if none is found
public PhoneEntry search(String fName, String lName) {

    int i = 0;

    if (fName.equals("")) {
    for (int j = 0; j < phoneBook.length; j++) {
        if (phoneBook[j].lastName.equals(lName)) {
                resultList[i] = phoneBook[j];
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    else {
    for (int j = 0; j < phoneBook.length; j++) {
        if (phoneBook[j].lastName.equals(lName) && phoneBook[j].firstName.equals(fName)) {
                resultList[i] = phoneBook[j];
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;

}


public void add(String fName, String lName, String phone) {

    for (int i = 0; i < phoneBook.length; i++) {
        if (phoneBook[i] == null) {
            phoneBook[i] = new PhoneEntry(fName, lName, phone); 
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("No room in phone book.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Tester:

```
import java.util.*;

public class PhoneBookTester {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    PhoneBook pb = new PhoneBook();
    PhoneEntry entry;

    // Create a new scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String lastName;
    String firstName;

    do {

    // Prompt the user to enter the name
    System.out.print("Pleast enter the last name to search: ");
    lastName = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Please enter the first name to search: ");
    firstName = input.nextLine();

    // search for the person
    entry = pb.search(firstName.toUpperCase(), lastName.toUpperCase());

    // if found, print out the entry
    if (entry != null) {
        //for(Phonebook eachEntry : pb.search(firstName.toUpperCase(), lastName.toUpperCase())) {
        System.out.println(entry.firstName + " " + entry.lastName + ": " + entry.phone);
    }

    // if user enter quit, then say good bye
    else if ("quit".equals(lastName)) {
        System.out.println("Good Bye!");
    }

    // if not found, tell the user
    else {
        System.out.println("Name not found.");
    }

    } while (!"quit".equals(lastName));
}
}
```

PhoneEntry:

```
public class PhoneEntry {

String firstName;    // first name of a person
String lastName;   // first name of a person
String phone;     // phone number of a person

// constructor
public PhoneEntry(String fName, String lName, String p) {

    firstName = fName.toUpperCase();
    lastName = lName.toUpperCase();
    phone = p;
}
}
```

Comment: So use List of PhoneEntries to return from your search method and check if firstName is empty then don't stop the search and add all the entries to the returning list.

Comment: you may have two methods like searchFirstName and searchLastName for this case.

Comment: where is the question ?

Comment: Start Stop:  Why did you remove the question?  Can you restore it please?  Normally after people answer, you either accept an answer, and/or upvote any that you found useful.  Can you please do this as well.  Thank you.

Comment: Don't deface posts (even your own) by removing all the question text & code.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

```
public PhoneEntry search(String fName, String lName) {
    // There could be 2 cases.
    // 1. There is only LastName == There is no First name
    // 2. There are First and Last name;    == There is First name
    // That means, you can easily handle this problem with checking whether there is first name
    int caseNumber = 0;     // Default number 0 will return null

    if(fName.equals("")) {      // if there is no first name
        caseNumber = 1;
    } else {
        caseNumber = 2;
    }

    PhoneBook[] searchResultList = new PhoneBook[]; // This will be result phonebook

    switch(caseNumber) {
        case 1:
            for (int j = 0; j < phoneBook.length; j++) {
                if (phoneBook[j].lastName.equals(lName)) {
                    searchResultList.add(phoneBook[j]);
                }
            }
            return searchResultList;
        case 2:
            for (int j = 0; j < phoneBook.length; j++) {
                if (phoneBook[j].lastName.equals(lName) && phoneBook[j].firstname.equals(fName)) {
                    searchResultList.add(phoneBook[j]);     // This could be mutiple. (There is possible situation that there is two person whose name is same and different phone number)
                }
            }
            return searchResultList;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

### And you can print the answer

```
for(Phonebook eachBook : pb.search(inputFName, inputLName)) {
    System.out.println(eachBook .firstName + " " + eachBook .lastName + ": " + eachBook .phone);
}
```

I don't know what exactly PhoneBook class is. So, I assume PhoneBook class has 3 variable, firstName, lastName, phone. So, please modify this answer that this codes fit your codes.

=========== Edit :: Add solution ===========

### main() class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create a new scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String lastName;
    String firstName;

    int variableForCountArray;

    do {

        PhoneBook pb = new PhoneBook();
        PhoneEntry[] entry;

        entry = null;
        variableForCountArray = 0;

        // Prompt the user to enter the name
        System.out.print("Pleast enter the last name to search: ");
        lastName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Please enter the first name to search: ");
        firstName = input.nextLine();

        // search for the person
        entry = pb.search(firstName.toUpperCase(), lastName.toUpperCase());

        // if found, print out the entry
        if (entry != null) {
            for(int i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {
                if(entry[i] != null) {      // Could get NullPointerException
                    variableForCountArray++;
                }
            }
            for(int index = 0; index < variableForCountArray; index++) {
                System.out.println(entry[index].firstName + " " + entry[index].lastName + ": " + entry[index].phone);
            }
        }

        // if user enter quit, then say good bye
        else if ("quit".equals(lastName)) {
            System.out.println("Good Bye!");
        }

        // if not found, tell the user
        else {
            System.out.println("Name not found.");
        }

    } while (!"quit".equals(lastName));

}
```

### PhoneEntry.java // No change

```
public class PhoneEntry {
    String firstName;    // first name of a person
    String lastName;   // last name of a person
    String phone;     // phone number of a person

    // constructor
    public PhoneEntry(String fName, String lName, String p) {
            firstName = fName.toUpperCase();
            lastName = lName.toUpperCase();
            phone = p;
    }
}
```

### PhoneBook.java

```
public class PhoneBook {

    PhoneEntry[] phoneBook;
    PhoneEntry[] resultList = new PhoneEntry[10];

    // constructor
    public PhoneBook() {

        phoneBook = new PhoneEntry[10];

        // load the phone book with data
        phoneBook[0] = new PhoneEntry("James", "Barclay", "(418) 665-1223");
        phoneBook[1] = new PhoneEntry("Grace", "Dunbar", "(860) 399-3044");
        phoneBook[2] = new PhoneEntry("Paul", "Kratides", "(815) 439-9271");
        phoneBook[3] = new PhoneEntry("Violet", "Smith", "(312) 223-1937");
        phoneBook[4] = new PhoneEntry("John", "Wood", "(913) 883-2874");
        phoneBook[5] = new PhoneEntry("John", "Smith", "(407) 123-4555");
    }

    // use linear search to find the targetName.
    // Return a reference to the matching PhoneEntry
    // or null if none is found
    public PhoneEntry[] search(String fName, String lName) {

        int i = 0;
        if (fName.equals("")) {
            for (int j = 0; j < phoneBook.length; j++) {
                if(phoneBook[j] != null) {
                    if (phoneBook[j].lastName.equals(lName)) {
                        resultList[i] = phoneBook[j];
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int j = 0; j < phoneBook.length; j++) {
                if(phoneBook[j] != null) {
                    if (phoneBook[j].lastName.equals(lName) && phoneBook[j].firstName.equals(fName)) {
                        resultList[i] = phoneBook[j];
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(i == 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return resultList;
        }

    }


    public void add(String fName, String lName, String phone) {

        for (int i = 0; i < phoneBook.length; i++) {
            if (phoneBook[i] == null) {
                phoneBook[i] = new PhoneEntry(fName, lName, phone); 
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("No room in phone book.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Print test result

```
Pleast enter the last name to search: smith
Please enter the first name to search: 
VIOLET SMITH: (312) 223-1937
JOHN SMITH: (407) 123-4555
Pleast enter the last name to search: smith
Please enter the first name to search: john
JOHN SMITH: (407) 123-4555
Pleast enter the last name to search: hello
Please enter the first name to search: 
Name not found.
Pleast enter the last name to search: quit
Please enter the first name to search: 
Good Bye!
```

Comment: @StartStop I am writing whole codes now. Please wait a moment.

Comment: How about using ```ArrayLIst<PhoneEntry>``` instead of ```PhoneEntry[]``` I am coding now but there is too many NPE to avoid.

Comment: @StartStop I am sure that this solution is bad because of too many possible Null pointer Exception. If I were you, I would rather to use ```ArrayList<>``` instead of array.

Answer (score 0):

Java8 approach.

PhoneEntry class:

```
public class PhoneEntry {
    final String firstName;
    final String lastName;
    final String phone;

    public PhoneEntry(String firstName, String lastName, String phone){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

PhoneBook class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class PhoneBook {
    List<PhoneEntry> contancts = new ArrayList<PhoneEntry>();

    public List<PhoneEntry> search(String lastName) {
        return contancts.stream()
                .filter(phoneEntry ->
                        phoneEntry.firstName.toLowerCase().equals(lastName.toLowerCase())
                                || phoneEntry.lastName.toLowerCase().equals(lastName.toLowerCase()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }

    public Optional<PhoneEntry> search(String firsName, String lastName){
        return contancts.stream()
                .filter(phoneEntry ->
                         phoneEntry.firstName.toLowerCase().equals(firsName.toLowerCase())
                                 && phoneEntry.lastName.toLowerCase().equals(lastName.toLowerCase()))
                .findFirst();
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PhoneBook phoneBook = new PhoneBook();

        phoneBook.contancts.add(new PhoneEntry("John","Xavier","(992)-30421-323"));
        phoneBook.contancts.add(new PhoneEntry("Mary","Doser","(992)-30421-353"));
        phoneBook.contancts.add(new PhoneEntry("George","Sesame","(990)-30421-353"));
        phoneBook.contancts.add(new PhoneEntry("Liam","Xavier","(990)-30211-353"));

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String lastName;
        String firstName;

        do {

            // Prompt the user to enter the name
            System.out.print("Pleast enter the last name to search: ");
            lastName = input.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Please enter the first name to search: ");
            firstName = input.nextLine();

            // search for the person
            Optional<PhoneEntry> entry = phoneBook.search(firstName, lastName);
            List<PhoneEntry> entries = phoneBook.search(lastName);
            // if found, print out the entry
            if (entry.isPresent() && firstName.length() !=0) {
                System.out.println(entry.get().firstName + " " + entry.get().lastName + ": " + entry.get().phone);
            }else if(firstName.length() == 0 && entries.size() !=0 ){
                entries.forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.firstName + " " + e.lastName + ": " + e.phone));
            }
            // if user enter quit, then say good bye
            else if ("quit".equals(lastName)) {
                System.out.println("Good Bye!");
            }
            // if not found, tell the user
            else {
                System.out.println("Name not found.");
            }

        } while (!"quit".equals(lastName));
    }
}
```